# Custom button class with sound when click

Tags: android, button

In my application I want set sound when click button and I used media player, it done. But it's very complicated when I have many buttons in many activity so I want create a button class that extends button and add sound in event click button.

Is it possible? And how can do it?

Comment: Why cant you try this way to search? 1) Custom Button in Android 2) Add media player features on event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.media.MediaPlayer;
        import android.util.AttributeSet;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.Button;

        public class CustomButton extends Button implements View.OnClickListener {

            Context mContext;
            public CustomButtonTest(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
                super(context, attrs, defStyle);
                mContext=context;
                init();
            }

            public CustomButtonTest(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
                super(context, attrs);
                mContext=context;
                init();
            }

            public CustomButtonTest(Context context) {
                super(context);
                mContext=context;
                init();
            }

            private void init(){
                setOnClickListener(this);
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Do something
                Log.d("TAG","@@@@@@@@@@ onClick");
                MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                mediaPlayer = mediaPlayer.create(mContext, R.raw.xoay_touch_sound); mediaPlayer.start();


               /*

                OR you can try below code also
                */

                /*Log.d("TAG","@@@@@@@@@@ onClick");
                int MAX_SOUND_POOL_STREAMS = 4;


                SoundPool soundPool = new SoundPool(MAX_SOUND_POOL_STREAMS,
                        AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100);
                int mySoundId = soundPool.load(mContext,
                        R.raw.xoay_touch_sound, 1);

                AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) mContext.getSystemService(mContext.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                float actualVolume = (float) audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                float maxVolume = (float) audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                float volume = actualVolume / maxVolume;
                soundPool.play(mySoundId, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);*/
            }

        }
```

XML

```
    <yourPakageName.CustomButton 
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
```

Comment: Thank you! But when I added code:
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.xoay_touch_sound);
        mediaPlayer.start(); in onClick it not run

Comment: Here you use MediaPlayer class ..MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.xoay_touch_sound).........use object  mediaPlayer .create(context, R.raw.xoay_touch_sound)

Comment: @Đời Cơbảnlà Buồn check updated code.If your written OnClickListener in your activity then 1st remove Listener then run code

Comment: it have sound but not fine because I want set default sound when click in button class and add new event when click button in activity.
But when I set event click in activity sound not run. hummmm...

Comment: You required Custom button OnClickListener .. then why your are written OnClickListener in Activity.You already Override on OnClickListener in Custom class.

Comment: because I want create a button when click it will have default sound and of course I can add event when click it in activity ex: next activity, show toast....

Comment: Ok but at time only one OnClickListener  is work..you can write common function for sound and call that function in activity OnClickListener

Comment: yep I did it and now I want custom button have default sound but it isn't impossible. Thank you very much.